# How many times can I install a retail version of Windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows

I built my own desktop and am currently running Linux on it but would like to buy Windows 10 and dual boot. Can I also install the same purchased (non-OEM version) copy of Windows 10 on a VM inside of my Linux OS?

I am asking specifically about the legality and not the logistics or implementation here.

Comment: See this page https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm

Comment: "You may use the backup copy we allow you to make or the media that the software came on to transfer the software. Every time you transfer the software to a new device, you must remove the software from the prior device. You may not transfer the software to share licenses between devices."

Comment: That’s not the relevant paragraph, see 2.d.iv. I believe questions about purely legal matters are off-topic on Super User, but I’m not entirely sure.

Comment: I guess I was just wondering what "device" means here. It's in the same hardware. I suppose I could set up a VM to boot from the HDD that the original dual boot is on at worst case?